# How do I remove a redirect after a form is submitted on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, forms

I'm reformatting part of an existing website so that what was previously two separate forms on two pages are now consolidated into one form on one page. I've got it consolidated, but cannot get rid of the redirect to the second page after form submission. How would I disconnect the pages so once the form is submitted, it just shows a confirmation and not the original second page.

I went through the main route to create redirects in on the page and on the form. For the page, I went to the Tools tab, then selected Redirection, but there was no existing redirection for the page. Same story with the form. Overall, I can't find how the form is redirecting to this second page and am not sure where to keep looking to remove it.

Comment: Which form did you use? for example: Contact form 7, WP forms, ninja forms, gravity forms.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I used gravity forms.